# UserId cannot be resolved to a type error java

Tags: java, eclipse

I am new to methods such as the public void stuff on Java.

If someone enters First Name as: John and surname: Smith. My program should display the UserID as jsmith. That all works fine when I put it all in the main method. I want it all on the same class (UserID) I also get an error message saying Insert assignment operator expression where it says:

```
process.userID;
```

Here's the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class UserID {

Scanner myScan = new Scanner (System.in);

char firstLetter;
String firstName;
String minCharacters;
String surname; 
String userID;

public void firstName () {
    System.out.print("Please enter your firstname: ");
    firstName = myScan.nextLine();
}

public void surname () {
    System.out.print("Please enter your surname: ");
    surname = myScan.nextLine();
}

public void userID (String userID) {
    firstLetter = firstName.charAt(0);
    minCharacters=surname.substring(0, 5);
    userID = firstLetter+minCharacters;
    System.out.print("User ID = " + userID.toLowerCase());
    System.out.println ("\nPlease keep a note of your User ID");

    myScan.close();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String userID;
    userID process = new UserID();
    process.userID;

}
```

}

Comment: Why do you have so many userID in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Adding on top of Daniel Stanley's answer, you are not calling firstname() and surname() methods in your main method or inside userId() method which takes input from Command Line.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
userID process = new UserID();
```

should be:

```
UserID process = new UserID(); //capital 'U'
```

and then:

```
process.userID("SomeString"); //add brackets
```

Comment: Hey, i get an error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at UserID.userID(UserID.java:23)
 at UserID.main(UserID.java:35)

Answer (score 0):

```
public void userID () {
firstLetter = firstName.charAt(0);

minCharacters=surname.length()>=5?surname.substring(0, 5):surname;
userID = firstLetter+minCharacters;
System.out.print("User ID = " + userID.toLowerCase());
System.out.println ("\nPlease keep a note of your User ID");

myScan.close();
```

}

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
UserID process = new UserID();
process.firstName();
process.surname();
process.userID();
```

}

Updated your code. It works. First issue was with UserID as Daniel pointed. Later, the surname can be less than 5 digit so it takes care of that. since you are using firstname and surname then you do not need to pass userId in the method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Code have some logical and Java naming convention errors;

I have edited you code respectively.

```
public class UserID {
    Scanner myScan = new Scanner(System.in);
    char firstLetter;
    String firstName;
    String minCharacters;
    String surName;
    String userID;

    public void setFirstName() {
        System.out.print("Please enter your firstname: ");
        this.firstName = myScan.nextLine();
    }

    public void setSurName() {
        System.out.print("Please enter your surname: ");
        this.surName = myScan.nextLine();
    }

    public void generateUserID() {
        firstLetter = firstName.charAt(0);
        minCharacters = surName;
        userID = firstLetter + minCharacters;
        System.out.print("User ID = " + userID.toLowerCase());
        System.out.println("\nPlease keep a note of your User ID");

        myScan.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String userID;
        UserID process = new UserID();
        process.setFirstName();
        process.setSurName();
        process.generateUserID();
    }
}
```

Feel free to ask anything.